# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type python3

Tags: python, if-statement

here is my code.

```
for i in output:
    if output[i] >= 0.80 and output[i] < 1 :
        output[i] = "very positive"
    elif output[i] >= 0.60 and output[i] < 0.80 :
        output[i] = "positive"
    elif output[i] >= 0.40 and output[i] < 0.60 :
        output[i] = "notr"
    elif output[i] >= 0.20 and output[i] < 0.40 :
        output[i] = "negative"
    elif output[i] >= 0 and output[i] < 0.20 :
        output[i] = "very negative"
```

and here is error.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-84cbeed85d45> in <module>
      1 for i in output:
----> 2     if output[i] >= 0.80 and output[i] < 1 :
      3         output[i] = "very positive"
      4     elif output[i] >= 0.60 and output[i] < 0.80 :
      5         output[i] = "positive"

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Output variable consists of values ​​between 0 and 1.

Comment: What is `output`? Share also it's value..

Comment: maybe you just want to look at i itself, not output[i] which doesn't mean anything. Wait, do you think i is an index? That's not how python works.

Comment: Values `between 0 and 1` are not integers. It seems like `i` is the actual value you are interested in. `for` loops over iterables in python give you the values in the loop variable, not indices.

Comment: Are you sure that ```for i in output``` is intended?

Comment: Everything is _already in the error_. Here's how I would make sense of the error: `IndexError`: Hmm, must be something in the array indexing operation. `arrays used as indices`: Hmm, what array am I using as an index? I can only see `[i]`, so it must be the array `i`. `must be of integer (or boolean) type`: Hmm, let me [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) my code and see what the type of `i` is. _Hey, look at that, it's an array of **not integers or booleans**_

Answer (score 1):

That's not how for loops work.
i is just a temporary which holds an actual value from output.
It is not an index. Assigning to it doesn't do anything useful. Your code probably was trying to do this:

```
output = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
for i in output:
    if i >= 0.80 and i < 1 :
        print (i, "very positive")
    elif i >= 0.60 and i < 0.80 :
        print (i, "positive")
    elif i >= 0.40 and i < 0.60 :
        print (i, "notr")
    elif i >= 0.20 and i < 0.40 :
        print (i, "negative")
    elif i >= 0 and i < 0.20 :
        print (i, "very negative")
```

> 0.1 very negative
> 0.2 negative
> 0.3 negative
> 0.4 notr
> 0.5 notr
> 0.6 positive
> 0.7 positive
> 0.8 very positive
> 0.9 very positive

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong with the value of i. with `for i in output` you are already selecting the values within the `output` list.
now you can replace all your `output[i]` with `i` like this:

```
for i in output:
    if i >= 0.80 and i < 1 :
        i = "very positive"
    elif i >= 0.60 and i < 0.80 :
        i = "positive"
    elif i >= 0.40 and i < 0.60 :
        i = "notr"
    elif i >= 0.20 and i < 0.40 :
        i = "negative"
    elif i >= 0 and i < 0.20 :
        i = "very negative"
```

or you can use this line:
`for i, val in enumerate(output):` .

Answer (score 0):

when you use the for loop `for i in output` , i is going to take the values present in your array 'output'.  for instance, if I have an array T containing names, this loop

```
for name in T:
    print name
```

will print all the names present in the array T.
Back to your problem now. You want to loop over your array. To do so, you used this:

```
for i in output:
```

Therefore, the values contained in your array will be stored in i. So your code should be:

```
for i in output:
if i >= 0.80 and i < 1 :
    i = "very positive"
elif i >= 0.60 and i < 0.80 :
    i = "positive"
elif i >= 0.40 and i < 0.60 :
    i = "notr"
elif i >= 0.20 and i < 0.40 :
    i = "negative"
elif i >= 0 and i < 0.20 :
    i = "very negative"
```

Hope this helps ^^

PS: in case you were trying to print those comments ("very negative, negative, notr,...), you should use print("[your comment]") instead of assigning that comment to i.